# Reformating an equation

Tags: self-learning

I have the formula $ f= \frac{\pi exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}}{\theta\sqrt3[1+exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}]^2}$

I am trying to convert it into the form $exp{[\frac{...}{...}]}$ but I am getting stuck.

I understand that $ \frac{\pi exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}}{\theta\sqrt3[1+exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}]^2} = \frac{exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}}{[1+exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}]^2} * exp\{ln\frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}$ but I'm not sure how to deal with the remaining terms.

Is it possible to get it in that form?

Comment: Let $z=\exp\{-(y-u) \frac{\pi}{\theta\sqrt3}\}$